# oracle 'ora-01843' date format error in the sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

i have a table and data as below

```
id joining_date

1  11-05-2020 04:15:57
```

I want to export from that table using date format

I am using:

```
select * from table where joining_date=TO_date('11-05-2020 04:15:57')
```

But I am getting `ora-01843` error

Please any one help .. let me know the result

Comment: you have to specify the format of the string, 'DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss' in your case inside the to_date, unless your session setting has this in the nls_date_format

Comment: Its working Thanks @gsalem

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timestamp constant for the comparison:

```
where joining_date = timestamp '2020-05-11 04:15:57'
```

This will work even if `joining_date` is stored as a `date` and not a `timestamp`.  `date`s are precise up to a second.

Answer (score 0):

> joining_date=TO_date('11-05-2020 04:15:57')

You are missing the required format mask:

```
TO_DATE ('11-05-2020 04:15:57', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```